# return ArrayList and printing objects within

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have a problem with an implementation of ArrayLists - I try to print my objects, but right now it only prints the memory adresses. I figure a loop is my savior somehow, but can't for the love of... figure out how to loop through my Course objects to make that happen. What am I missing? It can't be impossible or anything, it's just me being to stupid to figure it out (my forehead has a permanent imprint of my keyboard now).

```
public class Course{
    private String courseID;
    private String courseName;
    private int ap;
    private static ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Course programmeringGrund = new Course ("725G61", "Programmering Grundkurs", 6);
    Course itProjekt = new Course ("725G62", "IT-Projektledning - introduktion", 12);
    Course diskretMatematik = new Course ("764G06", "Diskret Matematik och Logik", 6);
    Course informatikTeknik = new Course ("725G37", "Informatik, teknik och lärande", 6);
    System.out.println(getCourses());

} public Course (String aCourseID, String aCourseName, int anAp){
    this.courseID=aCourseID;
    this.courseName=aCourseName;
    this.ap=anAp;
    courses.add(this);

} public static List getCourses(){
    return courses; 
}
```

Comment: Override the `toString` method in your `Course` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `toString()` method in `Course`.  The "memory address" printed is part of [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), and you haven't overridden `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Course 
{
    ...

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ID=" + courseID + ", Name=" + courseName;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: @Mark This answer is more of a completion to the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Traverse the `List` returned by `getCourses()` and print out values for each course `object`. Something like

```
  ArrayList<Course> mycourses = getCourses();
      for(Course obj: mycourses)
      {
      System.out.println("Id is "+obj.courseId);// So on you print everything    
      }
```

**OR** You can override the `toString()` Method in you `Course` class as ZouZou mentioned. As you haven't over ridden the `toString()` method as of now it is printing the memory address for the `List`